# How many rockets have been launched into space? (roughly, of course)

Tags: launch, history

First I was going to ask how many rocket bodies lay at the bottom of the ocean, but I simplified further.

Remember, this includes sounding rockets; anything passing the Kármán line.

I'm looking for a good guesstimate. I'm sure it's more than a thousand and less than a million, and guessing that it's probably about half-way between on a log scale (~31,600).

Food for thought; Gunter's Space Page has a map of launch sites worldwide http://space.skyrocket.de/directories/launchsites.htm Here's a screenshot at maximum zoom-out:

[image]

Comment: Jonathan McDowell has the numbers. http://www.planet4589.org/space/lvdb/index.html

Comment: @pericynthion I see a whole lot of data, but "the number" may take some  effort to find.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

About 35,000-40,000, including sounding rockets.

Ordinarily I'd provide a hard source, but since you specifically asked for a guesstimate I'll just cite myself: My answer [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/13402/195) claims ~5,000 *orbital* launches; unfortunately I failed to cite my source there and can't recall where I got that data -- I don't *think* I added up all the entries linked from Wikipedia's [Timeline of Spaceflight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_spaceflight) article, but it's possible that I did.

Jonathan McDowell's list of [suborbital space launches](http://www.planet4589.org/space/lvdb/index.html), updated 9/2017, includes this summary:

> This database forms the background data for a comprehensive launch list of 70536 launches. The launches include 5704 orbital launch attempts, 28466 suborbital launches, and 36366 endoatmospheric flights

So this would be between 28466 and 34170 depending on how many of the orbital launch attempts reached space.

Comment: http://space.skyrocket.de/directories/launchsites.htm

Comment: See [pericynthion](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/23696/#comment67814_23696)'s comment.

Comment: That makes your initial estimate Quite Good Actually. Revising...

Comment: I added up all the launches in the Timeline of Spaceflight article and got: 5178 Full launch successes, 108 Partial failures, i.e. lower-than-expected orbit or failure of secondary mission, 394 Failures to reach orbit, and 249 Future scheduled missions. So ~5000 sounds right

Comment: Looking good! How is the number 34170 calculated?

Comment: 70536 = 5704 (orbital launch attempts) + 28466 (suborbitals) + 36366 (endoatmospheric). If all of the 5704 orbital launch attempts blew up below the Kármán line, then 28466; if all of them reached space but failed to orbit, then 34170, and it's certainly somewhere in between.

Comment: Does that include all the ICBMs/SLBMs/... launched for testing?

Comment: @RussellBorogove I didn't get (or at least see) a flag for your comment, just happened to see it it now. Thanks!

Comment: @MartinSchröder I couldn't swear to "all", but the database includes many launches of e.g. Atlas, Polaris, and Minuteman, with annotations suggesting tests and military exercises, as well as Russian launchers such as UR-100N (aka SS-19 STILETTO).

Answer (score 8):

Scott Manley had re-[tweeted](https://twitter.com/jonkeegan/status/1052985931878334465) about this.

The Economist's [The space race is dominated by new contenders](https://www.economist.com/graphic-detail/2018/10/18/the-space-race-is-dominated-by-new-contenders) is paywalled, but here's the first bit, and the graphic.

[image]

> Source: FAA; Jonathan McDowell/planet4589.org, Roscosmos, press reports; United Launch Alliance, Franc,e Italy, and European Space Agency (ESA)
>
> Some 4,500 satellites circle Earth, providing communications services and navigational tools, monitoring weather, observing the universe, spying and doing more besides. Getting them there was once the business of the superpowers’ armed forces and space agencies. Now it is mostly done by companies and the governments of developing countries.

Print edition Oct 18th 2018