# Why do we not fly to space with helicopters? What are the practical altitude limits?

Tags: spacecraft, spacecraft-development, uncrewed-spaceflight

People will tell that there is no air, and this is why we cannot. But if I read on the internet, there is air in space, much less, but still something.

For example:

- 100 km: $6\ \cdot 10^{-7}$ times as much air as on the surface;
- 1000 km: $2.5\ \cdot 10^{-14}$ times as much air as on the surface;
- even on 36000 km there is something ($1.5\ \cdot 10^{-18}$ times as much air as on the surface or 30000 atoms per 1 cubic decimeter).

Talking practically:
NASA already built a prototype of the helicopter which will fly on Mars where the atmosphere is the same as 30 km high on The Earth.

if I take some software to calculate propeller thrust like this [Propeller Selector](http://www.hoppenbrouwer-home.nl/ikarus/software/propselector.htm) and I calculate this very particular practical example.
If I take this [propeller](https://hobbyking.com/en_us/tcf-precision-carbon-fiber-propeller-32x12-1pc.html) which cost 50 euro and this [engine](https://www.banggood.com/Racerstar-Racing-Edition-2205S-BR2205S-2300KV-2-4S-Brushless-Motor-For-X210-220-QAV250-FPV-Frame-p-1096933.html?cur_warehouse=UK) which cost 9 euro, then I can fly up to 30 km with only 381 watts of power for 8140 rpm. Fly I mean it will produce 1 kg thrust, which enough to hold 29 grams engine, 349 grams propeller and let say 500 grams for the power source (we can even use a solar panel for it). Calculations are shown in the picture below:

[image]

and the same configuration will fly (produce same 1 kg thrust) on the surface with only 47 watts of power and just 1000 rpm.

If I go forward, I can calculate that to fly on 100 km I will need 25 meters (1000 inches) diameter propeller and just about 800 watts of power with rotation speed 500 rpm.

[image]

I general, we just need big enough propeller, and because of very low air pressure, we will not need a lot of power to make it rotating fast. Also, we can make propeller very thin, because it should not be very strong, because of low pressure as well. Another point, that we can use different propellers for different altitudes, like many stages rockets.

Ultimately, if we make a few kilometer size propeller we can theoretically even fly to Mars and other planets. There are still 30000 atoms per 1 cubic decimeter in space.

**UPDATE 1:**

Thank you, everyone, for very valuable comments. I will do exact calculations with the real propeller, motor and solar panel to see how high we can go.

The main problems as I understand is the weight of propeller + power source and strength of the material of propeller.

**UPDATE 2:**

Real calculation of helicopter with solar panels :)

If I take this [real propeller](https://www.mt-propeller.com/pdf/TCDS_EASA(Europe)/MTV-33_Issue1.pdf) which is 6.5 kg and 70 inch diameter, this [real motor](https://hobbyking.com/en_us/turnigy-3648-brushless-motor-1450kv.html) with 1600W power and these row [solar panels](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/300-Pcs-4-5W-4BB-A-Grade-156MM-x-156MM-Polycrystal-Silicon-Solar-Cell-For-DIY/32677454634.html) with the weight with the weight 4.5 kg for 1350 watt (or 1 kg gives 300 watt) and I add 50% of mass of the solar panel to the mounting of them.

My calculation with the same program (*Propeller Selector*) shows that it can fly up to 5km taking into account mass of propeller, the mass of motor, the mass of solar panels, the mass of solar panel mounting, max motor power, max propeller rpm, max motor rpm.

If solar panels were 10 times lighter, then 20 km could be reached.

So far, I see only 2 problems:

1. The weight of the solar panel. If we can make it 10 times lighter,
   then we can reach much higher altitude.
2. This program can give wrong results for altitudes higher than 5-10 km.

Other problems from comments:

- Rotor speed being higher than orbit speed. Calculation shows that it is not
  necessary and Karman line depends on aircraft weight. So, if we make
  very lite aircraft/airplane from non-existing/"future invented" material
  (carbon epoxy, etc.), then Karman line will be higher than 100 km.
- Shock wave when propeller parts are moving faster than sound. One comment was, that it is not a big problem if air density is very small. So we can start with low speed on the ground and reach high speed propeller when we reach higher altitude.
- The strength of the material. In my last picture with 25 m (1000 inch) propeller, if I calculate  acceleration and g-force it will be 3500g, yes, 10 times more than normal helicopters (Mi-26 helicopter with 32 m propeller and 132 rpm). But, considering that piston inside V8 Formula 1 car engine works with 8500g, then it is kind of feasible). Maybe they do not do it for real helicopters because of sound speed, but as I told before, it does not matter at high altitudes.

Comment: @OrganicMarble It can be true with high probability, that this program does not work well higher than 10km. But anyway, I calculated from generic momentum conservation law and it gives similar results, we just need big propeller and even 30000 atoms per 1 cubic decimeter can be abough.

Comment: Question 2: Do propellers work outside of the continuum flow regime?  Specifically, in the free molecular flow regime? Look up what a Knudsen number is.

Comment: The Karman line would be a hard ceiling - the blade tips would have to be traveling at a rate comparable to orbital velocity to generate any lift.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I imagine your propeller will start to look like a turbomolecular pump's inlet at these pressures; a simple wedge to impart downwards velocity

Comment: Li-ion batteries have specific powers topping out at 340 W/kg per Wikipedia.  500g of battery is not sufficient, let alone 500g of solar panel.  Worse, 30km * 1kgf is approx 300kJ; Li-ion specific energies are apparently around 400-900 kJ/kg, so you're at the very edge of the energy capacity there assuming perfect efficiency (which you won't get).

Comment: It is not what you envision, but there is some precedent for space helicopters. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary_Rocket

Comment: Even if your payload is only 1g, you're going to need a lot more than 1kg of thrust to lift your fuel to orbit.

Comment: "0.0000006 times less air" is something like a double negation. It means there is more air because the number is smaller than one.

Comment: Helicopter altitude record is 12 km, a long way from space. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_altitude_record

Comment: Actually, helicopter *rotor* lift is almost identical to airplane wing lift.

Comment: @Hobbes of course, that's partly because helicopters are not usually designed for high-altitude flight (if you have a reason to go that high, you usually want an airplane). A helicopter could be designed for higher altitude flight; the main limitation is getting enough engine power at high altitudes and keeping the rotor tips subsonic.

Comment: "NASA already built a prototype of the helicopter which will fly on Mars where the atmosphere is the same as 30 km high on The Earth." - You have to account for the fact that Mars gravity is not the same as Earth gravity.

Comment: `and because of very low air pressure, we will not need a lot of power to make it rotating fast` You're selling the low pressure as a positive point, but it's a negative one. The lack of air pressure also means the lack of "pushing off" by spinning the blades. In order to create the same amount of upward force in a lower air pressure, you need to spin the blades _faster_.

Comment: The point of going to space is to have a (virtually endless) __free fall__. Even if it was possible to lift some cargo with a helicopter (or more realistically a balloon; the altitude record for unmanned balloons appears to be 53.0 km), it would not give you many of the benefits we have from spaceflight, would it? It could not replace the functionality of most satellites. And if you put a space laboratory there, it would not be "weightless", so there would be little useful research to do that you could not have done on the surface.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78527/discussion-on-question-by-zlelik-why-do-we-not-fly-to-space-with-helicopters-wh).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: To be fair, being able to launch a rocket from that altitude counters many problems regarding needed delta V and aerodynamics. From the edge of the atmosphere, you could launch virtually any shape of vehicle with a considerably smaller thrust stage.

Comment: @Zlelik Your second calculation, which is still only very preliminary, has dramatically reduced the altitude you can reach.  You want your materials to be ten times lighter than normal ones.  Reducing the quoted weight of the solar panels by 90% takes *4 kilograms* off the helicopter.  So your payloads for this version of the helicopter, WITH the future materials, can only weigh kilograms and will have strict power requirements, before you ever get to altitudes where the air won't hold you up.

Comment: A helicopter in space is just a very dangerous brick.

Comment: All of the other problems notwithstanding, has anyone mentioned heat dissipation yet? You might find it hard keeping your rotors going if your electricals melt when operating in a near-vacuum

Comment: My mind blew when I saw that figure for 100km. a 25 meter roter with 7 meter pitch, rotating at 500rpm. Produced 1.24kg thrust.. To make this work, you need to build your helicopter with power source, and THAT HUGE ROTOR, with a mass budget of something less than 1.24 kilograms. Even an Aerogel of that size would weigh more! Remember your rotor is at supersonic speed (mach 2.5). Remember your rotor tip will experience 3550 gravities of centrifugal force.

Answer (score 70):

A 25m diameter rotor has a perimeter of around 78 meters. At that size, at 500rpm, the rotor tips would be going in excess of 1,400mph.

At those kind of speeds, even though it doesn't take much power to get a very light rotor going, there is still an awful lot of force involved which has to be handled by the materials to prevent them literally tearing themselves apart.

Comment: Not to mention that that's Mach 2, and the shockwaves will do nasty things to your lift.

Comment: This would give a radial acceleration at the tip of some ~34000$ms^{-2}$ (~3500g) - better hope your spacecopter doesn't skip rotor day.

Comment: It is normal for helicopters. Check this one "Bell UH-1 Iroquois" in Wikipedia. 392 rpm and 14 meters propeller diameter. and it works fine, nothing happens.

Soviet Mil Mi-26 has 32 meters propeller and 132 rpm.

I am not sure about shockwave in high altitudes like 100km? Will it exist?

Comment: @Hobbes It would be Mach 2 at ground-level, but don't forget the speed of sound changes with air density and temperature. At a 100 km height, the speed of sound would be far higher than the orbital speed. 100km isn't just a random "this is space number" - the Kármán line is the boundary where you cannot maintain altitude using lift anymore, even with perfect airfoils; the speed required for lift to cancel weight is equal to the orbital speed at that altitude.

Comment: @Luaan the practical limit being of course, much lower.

Comment: @Zlelik No, helicopter blades cannot exceed the speed of sound - even ignoring the massive damage that would cause, it would cause them to lose all lift, losing control of the craft (don't forget that while one blade is supersonic, the opposing blade isn't). Not everything has a linear relationship, you know - you need to understand how things scale. Neither 14 m @ 392 RPM nor 32 m @ 132 RPM give you a good idea o how 25 m @ 500 RPM would behave.

Comment: @Luaan: the speed of sound is a bit lower at 100 km than at ground level (270 m/s at 100 km, 330 m/s at ground level), see https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/sound.html

Comment: @Zlelik It's normal for helicopter blades to go more than twice as fast as the fastest helicopter blades in the world? Not really following your logic here.

Comment: @Hobbes That doesn't quite go up to 100 km (and no idea how accurate it's supposed to be even at the maximum altitude they support), but you're probably right that the speed of sound is smaller  than (or at least similar to) ground level, certainly not similar to the orbital speed. My bad. Too bad I can't edit that bit of the comment anymore :D

Comment: @Moyli 2 times faster is not a big deal I believe. If it would be 10 or 100 times faster, then I would agree it is not possible, but 2 times is feasible. Also 25 meters and 500 rpm is just an example. I believe other calculation can be done with bigger propeller, but lower speed. Need to see if thrust depends on propeller size and rpm linearly or not.

Comment: @Zlelik 2 times faster **is** a big deal in this context. As soon as your blades start to reach the speed of sound, everything about their behaviour changes *dramatically*, and every one of those changes is going to cause severe problems for any aircraft that wants to remain airborne.

Comment: @Zlelik You can do the math yourself. 392 rpm / 60 seconds is about 6.5 rotations per second. The tip of a propeller travels the perimeter of the circle it sweeps out every rotation. Perimeter is `diameter * pi` or about 44 meters. So the tip travels 44m 6.5 times per second or 286m/s. The [speed of sound at sea level is 340 m/s](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=speed+of+sound+at+sea+level). [At the UH-1's service ceiling, 6000m, it's 320m/s](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=speed+of+sound+at+6000m).

Comment: Human muscles *alone* are sufficient to overcome gravity! If you just build a series of steps, you can JUMP your way to orbital altitudes!! This design is simple, clear, and so obvious that I wonder that no one has tried it! YOU COULD BE FIRST!!!

Answer (score 55):

At 100 km altitude, you get to the [Karman line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A1rm%C3%A1n_line). This is the altitude where you have to fly at orbital speed to get sufficient lift. This definition is based on the lift equation, which applies to all airfoils including that of a helicopter rotor.

So in a helicopter at 100 km altitude, your blades have to travel at orbital speed (27,000 km/h or 17,000 mph) to generate enough lift.

Because the blades rotate, the inside of the blade travels at a lower speed and the outside travels at a higher speed. Taking the average, the midpoint of your blades would have to revolve at 27,000 km/h.

If you want to get into orbit instead of having to keep spending energy on hovering, you have to fly at 27,000 km/h. When you do that, the advancing blade moves at 54,000 km/h relative to the air. The receding blade moves at 0 km/h relative to the air. The heating effects alone would be enough to melt your blades in a short time.*

I wouldn't want to cope with the aerodynamics of blades that go from 0 to 54,000 km/h twice per rotation, nor with the centrifugal forces in the rotor system.

*: in a rocket launch, the fairing is usually jettisoned at an altitude of ~100 km, when the heating effect drops below 1 kW/m<sup>2</sup>. The rocket is far below orbital speed at that point (5000 km/h?). Aerodynamic heating scales with the square of the speed, so a helicopter rotor would be subject to 100 times that.

### Alternative approach

Approaching from a different angle: at 100 km, atmospheric pressure is 10<sup>-7</sup> bar. So your rotor blades need to have 10<sup>7</sup> times the area to get the amount of lift you need to hover. Your propeller has an area of 32"x1" (roughly), at 100 km that goes to 32 million sq in = 222,000 sq ft is 20,000 m<sup>2</sup> is a propeller longer than a Boeing 747. There's no way to make a structure that large within your weight budget. 
You could increase lift by increasing speed, but then you're back to supersonic propellers.

### First principles

The lift of an aerofoil (any aerofoil, including a helicopter rotor) is governed by this equation:

$$L = \tfrac12\rho v^2 S C_L$$

L is the lift force
ρ is the air density
v is the aircraft's speed relative to the air
S is the aircraft's wing area,
$C_L$ is the lift coefficient.

When you go from ground level to 100 km, ρ reduces from 10<sup>5</sup> Pa to 0.01 Pa (data from atmospheric models [discussed here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/18223/atmospheric-density-vs-altitude)). 
That means lift also reduces by a factor of 10<sup>7</sup>. You have to compensate for that by either increasing the speed by a factor 10<sup>3.5</sup> or increasing your wing area by a factor of 10<sup>7</sup>, or a combination of both.

Both inevitably increase weight, which means you need more lift. This is a vicious cycle, and at altitudes far below 100 km you get to a situation where no material in existence is light enough to make your helicopter work.

Comment: I am not sure if it's fair to consider heating effects from the air resistance. The pressure is very low up there and I believe the actual resistance will be equal to what blades usually resist. Just as the downforce will be the same.

Comment: Why would one have to have a forward speef of 25000 mph? A helicopter can have lift without forward speed (and if it has that speed, it already is in orbit).

Comment: The only point of flying at that altitude is to get into orbit, because then you can remain up there without using more fuel.

Comment: @Hobbes see [this comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/27630/why-do-not-we-fly-to-space-with-helicopters-what-are-the-practical-altitude-lim#comment82483_27632)

Comment: This answer is really confusing. At the Karman line the blades need to move at orbital speed and the Helicopter can hover in place. They don't go from 0 - 50k mph, the blades are rotating at an even speed. Anything in orbit at that height would suffer from the same heating effect; I'm pretty sure that's negligible.

Comment: Hovering costs a lot of energy. If you want to spend more than a few minutes at that altitude it's cheaper to get into orbit. And for pretty much any function you want, data quality improves with more time spent there.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann What Hobbes said. Also note that helicopters are *extremely bad at hovering*. They still rely on forward motion to produce lift at a reasonable cost - if you can't maintain lift while having forward motion comparable to blade velocity, you don't even come *close* to maintaining lift while hovering.

Comment: Not to neglect the heating effects, but the required power to turn a rotor this fast is also shocking at a glance.  Each rotor blade does a 360-degree orbital plane change with each revolution of the rotor (since it's at orbital velocity).

Comment: "This is the altitude where you have to fly at orbital speed to get sufficient lift." - This is not correct.  At the Karman line you have to fly at orbital speed to generate lift that is strong enough to counteract gravity. This is significantly more than sufficient lift - we can see this since when we are moving at orbital speed sufficient lift would be 0N.

Answer (score 33):

Space is really like this [(XKCD What if)](https://what-if.xkcd.com/58/)

[image]

In theory a plane could reach most of the way to space, but it won't be able to reach orbital speeds.

Bottom line, it just isn't practical. Maybe someday a helicopter could lift a rocket up high, which would help a bit, but it really just isn't practical. Also, a balloon might just be better in any case, it can go higher and lift more payload.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78434/discussion-on-answer-by-pearsonartphoto-why-do-not-we-fly-to-space-with-helicopt).

Comment: This misses the point of using a helicopter. If you can provide sufficient upward thrust you don't need orbital velocity. Not that I believe any propeller would provide said thrust is space. The same goes for a plane, if it still actually has *lift*, then it doesn't need to achieve orbit.

Comment: @Octopus You need *orbital velocity* to be *in orbit*, and not going into orbit is pointless, as anything useful you could be doing is done in orbit.

Comment: It would be cheaper to just use a balloon in any case. I don't think there is anything aside from accuracy that a helicopter can do that a balloon could not do.

Comment: @Octopus 100 km is the highest even theoretically you could be via a pure air powered spacecraft (Definition of Karman line). That is too low for most purposes.

Comment: @Polygnome. Not true. The Virgin Galactic vehicles went into space without going into orbit. They did not need orbital velocity. If they had been able to provide thrust to counteract their weight then they would be in space without orbital velocity. This is exactly the concept the OP is trying to get at. Orbital velocity does only one thing, it allows you stay in space without exerting energy. All things could be geostationary at any altitude if they had sufficient thrust. That would be *very* useful!

Comment: @Octopus the fact that an imaginary thing would be useful if it were real does not make it real.

Comment: @Octopus No, it would be incredible wasteful to constantly expel energy... you would extremely quickly lose any advantage you think this imaginary thing might have. Sure, if we had a ZPM that gave us infinite power this might be helpful, but then again, if we have that tech then we need not consider such small things. I think my point still stands, its just a pointless mind exercise without any *real* application.

Comment: @Octopus a helicopter rotor is still a wing. And when physics say "X speed needed to generate any lift", they include helicopter rotors - and probably tear them to pieces on the technicality when accelerating: There will be an awkward moment when the outer part of a rotor blade generates lift, the inner is too slow yet...

Comment: @Polygnome better tell all the people who launch *sub-orbital sounding rockets* for atmospheric and space science ([**by far** the majority](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/23698/12102) of all rocket launches on Earth) that their work is pointless then.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto BBC: [The New Lighter-than-Air Race for Space](http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20180604-the-new-lighter-than-air-race-for-space)

Comment: @uhoh They aren't, but we were talking about replacing orbital launches at least in part with this technique - which simply won't fly. or tell me at least *one* concrete area where this would be useful (in terms of saving money). You certainly won't hang a geostationary TV satellite by a propeller for example, coverage is much too small and the weight too big.

Comment: @uhoh I wasn't talking about the OP, but about what followed this answer

Comment: This answer probably needs an explanation of *why* you need to reach orbit and why can't just keep going straight up to leave earth's gravity (or why "not going into orbit is pointless", or what the problem is with trying to do it with a helicopter specifically).

Answer (score 24):

The propellor needs to be strong enough not to pull itself apart via centrifugal force.  If you go through the math, you find that the maximum [stress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_(mechanics)) on the propellor blade will be halfway along its length, and will have the value
$$
\sigma = \frac{1}{4}\rho L \omega^2,
$$ 
where $\omega$ is the blade's angular velocity (usually measured in radians/second) and $\rho$ is the density of the material (usually measured in kilograms per cubic meter.)  Re-arranging this, we find that the [specific strength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_strength) of the propeller material must be
$$
\frac{\sigma}{\rho} = \frac{L \omega^2}{4}.
$$

For a 12.5-meter length blade rotating at 500 rpm, this works out to be
$$
\frac{\sigma}{\rho} \approx 34 \text{ kN}\cdot\mathrm{m/kg},
$$
which is still within the realm of known materials.  However, as you get higher, you'll need to increase either the size of the blades, their rotation rate, or (probably both);  and eventually you'll get to the point where you have to build your helicopter blades out of unobtanium.

Comment: At Joe's House of Unobtanium, we're OVERLOADED with space rotors. At low low low prices. That's Joe's!!

Comment: `+1` Yay for a science and math-based answer!

Answer (score 19):

OrganicMarble touched on this in a comment but I think it deserves an answer as well, since the question doesn't stop at the Karman line (approx. 100km if you're really defining it as the height where the velocity required to generate lift exceeds the orbital velocity).

In simplest terms:  just because there's a few atoms of gas present at some height doesn't mean it's acting like a gas does at sea level.

Part of the reason a wing (and make no mistake, a helicopter's rotor is absolutely a wing for these purposes) works at all is because air fills in around it.  Air rushes in behind it because air molecules fly around and bounce off of each other and fill up space, and so you can keep pushing down air, which in turn pushes up your wing and whatever is attached to it.

This is really aerodynamically important!  The wing doesn't have to literally hit a molecule of air to get involved with that molecule, because the molecules are involved with each other.  The wing or rotor disc can use a lot of the air around it!

As height increases and the ambient pressure drops (because gravity drags the air down, and there's only so much air around for the other air to essentially stand on top of) that space-filling effect really isn't happening anymore.  The air molecules are doing a lot less bouncing (their [mean free path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_free_path) is longer) and so once you push them out of the way there's nothing left to push down on.  You essentially only interact with the air you hit.

All that is to say this premise

> Ultimately, if we make a few kilometer size propeller we can theoretically even fly to Mars and other planets. There are still 30000 atoms per 1 cubic decimeter in space.

is wrong.  Once you can't fill in air for the propeller to grab, you're essentially just as likely to bounce your 30,000 atoms off the top than the bottom.  This doesn't matter for something like a vacuum pump, because if the molecule bounces off the top eventually it should get another chance to come back to the pump by bouncing off the vacuum chamber's walls.  When you're in open space, **it means the net force your propeller can create is zero.**

If you're an experimentalist, this is trivially true just by observing that the Space Shuttle had giant wings and completely ignored the lift that it generated while it was in Low Earth Orbit.  The International Space Station also has giant wings (the solar arrays!) and mostly thinks of those in terms of drag.  Think of how many cubic decimeters the ISS has intersected in its decades on orbit!  (Lift generation for both is actually more favorable for both of these than for your helicopter, since they move sideways at terrific speeds, thus encountering regions where they haven't already hit all the available air molecules.)

Comment: Nice explanation!

Answer (score 15):

We don't fly to space with helicopters because we can't.  We would if we could, believe me.

Aside from all the very valid concerns raised by others, the question doesn't properly account for weight*.  Maybe your 32 inch diameter propeller weighs 349 grams, but the 10m one certainly doesn't.  Oh no!  Now 1kg thrust won't lift it at all!  So you need more power!  So you need more fuel/energy!  So you need more thrust...

Solar panels won't solve your problem.  They sound great when you don't need a lot of power, but their specific power (Watts per kilogram) doesn't hold up versus something like a jet turbine or rocket engine.  Batteries also don't have specific energies (Joules per kilogram) comparable to hydrocarbon fuels yet.

The [world's current helicopter altitude record](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-highest-altitude-an-average-helicopter-can-fly) is a bit less than 41,000 feet.  Ultimately helicopters just can't put enough power into the air to continue lifting themselves.  They all eventually hit a thrust-to-weight ratio of 1, even though a turbine helicopter has vastly more power available than the helicopter you're proposing.

Why does the proposed Mars helicopter work while yours wouldn't?  Because it doesn't go very far.  The power requirements favor a small helicopter, since the weight drops so much more rapidly than the thrust as it scales down, but the flight times being talked about are [about 90 seconds](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/news.php?feature=7121) (much like terrestrial drones!)  So it couldn't make it from an Earth Sea Level equivalent altitude to the proposed Mars Equivalent altitude; it would run out of energy before it got there.

(*I see in comments on other answers that you've said it's "just a matter of propeller and solar panels weight."  It is, but you can't make them arbitrarily light.  There's no scaling law that even suggests they'll get dramatically lighter over the next couple decades.)

Comment: Thanks, a good answer. I will do exact calculations with 32 Inch propeller and solar panels to see, how high it can go :)

Comment: The Marscopter also doesn't need as much thrust to lift a given mass through a given density of air, since Mars has much lower gravity than Earth.

Comment: That's true, but they've also done Mars-atmosphere demo flights on Earth, without tethers, so it doesn't rely on the gravity difference.  https://youtu.be/oOMQOqKRWjU

Answer (score 4):

The propeller would still weigh a lot!

- You don't want it to bend 90 degree in direction of flight or bend in opposite direction of rotation, which requires some stiffness which does not come cheap in terms of weight. it cannot be very thin.
- Also I would assume at the base it must me as thick(or similar) as your 81cm propeller base at sea level to support the weight of your aircraft. Let us assume a linear drop in thickness to the tips. Even without calculation I can tell you it will be very heavy.

Comment: Then it is just about propeller weight. We can use many propellers, like thick one for the base, later at 20 km we through it away and start using second thinner and bigger one etc... Or maybe in 10-20 years they will invent something strong enough to make a big propeller. This 81 cm propeller is only 350 grammes. Very light.

Also, we can bring just parts to space, like they built International Space Station, and assemble 5 km size propeller there and start flying from there to Mars.

Comment: @Zlelik: You would also need propellant to run the engine with, and you need to lift that as well. To lift that, you're going to need a larger propeller… the [tyranny of the rocket equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation). Also, every time you think _"I found a **simple** way to solve a problem countless expert have worked on for decades"_ you should stop and think where you're having vital knowledge problems.

Comment: @DarkDust This is why I asked here, when I found "a simple way to solve the problem".

About fuel. Let's use solar panel, then solar energy is 1000 Watt per 1m2. Solar panel has 20% Efficiency and we have 200 Watts electricity from 1m2. Then if we make lite enough solar panel and lite enough propeller we can go up and stay at the same altutude (for example 100 km) for any time.

Maybe it is just a matter of propeller and solar panels weight and we just need to wait for 10-20 years, when it will be lite enough.

Comment: @Zlelik, the lightest solar panel I was able to find while looking at portable panels came in at around 22 grams per watt.  Hook that up to your proposed 29 gram engine and 349 gram propeller, and you're looking at 996 grams of solar panels to provide the 47 watts you say are required -- somewhat over the 500 grams you can lift at sea level.  "If we make it out of unobtanium, it'll work" sounds good, until you actually try to find some unobtanium.

Comment: Let them flex--the outward force way exceeds the lift they generate.  You only need to maintain the angle of attack.

Comment: @Mark Will do Exact calculations with the solar panels. Thanks for a good example.