# What are the most used American sounding rockets?

Tags: sounding-rocket

From all the [sounding rockets](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sounding_rocket) used by USA which model has/had the most widespread use?

Comment: What is a "sounding rocket"?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sounding_rocket - there have been more sounding rockets reaching space than orbital rockets.

Comment: *Reviewers: "sounding rocket" is coming from "sonde" ($\approx$ "probe") and has nothing to do to "sound".*

Comment: @JoeJobs there certainly have by far, as discussed in answers to [How many rockets have been launched into space? (roughly, of course)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23696/12102).