# Is SpaceX on the way to a reliability record?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, failure, record

One of the most striking phenomena of Falcon 9 launches is how smoothly they go, at least for the outside spectator.

SpaceX launches a lot. Apparently, they have now had [109 successful missions in a row](https://www.elonx.net/spacex-statistics/) after the [Amos-6 failure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMOS-6_(satellite)). (And because that was a static fire test that went wrong I think it is not even a proper a launch failure).

- Is this the longest stretch of successful missions ever by a single agency or company?
- Since most (or all?) of these were Falcon 9 launches, is it the longest stretch *for a model*?
- If not, how many more successful launches (for SpaceX respectively the Falcon 9) would it take to beat the current record?

Comment: Tory Bruno is famous for [making ULA's reliability known on twitter](https://twitter.com/torybruno/status/1468289520659533829)

Comment: @BrendanLuke15 Ah, interesting. The Delta Heavy launch didn't reach orbit though.

Comment: It did, [28500 / 2004-050A](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/nmc/spacecraft/displayTrajectory.action?id=2004-050A), it just failed to *directly inject* the payload into GEO

Comment: Highly related, probable duplicate  https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/52392/is-there-a-record-for-unbroken-series-of-successful-launches-by-some-objective?rq=1

Comment: @OrganicMarble I agree, that's about my question. Feel free to vote for dup closure. I can also delete it but maybe it's not bad to have a search engine anchor every 6 months ;-).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I think if you vote for dupe closure, it will only take your vote to do it.  I understand this is an evolving story, but probably better to post updated answers to the other question, once SX passes ULA.

Comment: @OrganicMarble OK, I did.

Comment: Well, guess I was wrong about that one.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I think you're partly right, the final "Community" vote to close is actually the OP's vote (the Community bot's username is occasionally used as a proxy for other user names that for some reason it doesn't want to name) It seems to take *less users* to close when the OP concurs, but apparently still a few others.

Comment: @uhoh I thought i remembered voting to close my own question as a duplicate a couple of times on Ask Ubuntu and it insta-closed (after asking me if I was sure) but maybe that's not what happened.

Comment: @Organic No, it didn't insta-close. There may be differences between the forums, or it is a matter of xp.